# simple JFflex parser translates to java OK. Error when compiling java code

Tags: parsing, jflex

I have this simple Bison JFLEX parser :
http://pastebin.com/SNB20y7G

I ran jflex parser.flex ( this is how my file is called) obtained a class called TuringLexer.java
When I try to compile it with javac TuringLexer.java I get this:

```
$ javac TuringLexer.java
TuringLexer.java:482: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Yytoken
location: class TuringLexer
  public Yytoken yylex() throws java.io.IOException {
         ^
1 error
```

Any clue what the issue might be? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had forgotten to add:

```
%public
%class TuringLexer
%type Void
```

instead of just

```
   %class TuringLexer
```

now the .java file works aswell